# Adding AWS Cognito to IdentityServer4 as an OIDC Provider

Tags: c#, amazon-cognito, identityserver4

I've been trying to add AWS Cognito as an External Provider to my IdentityServer4 instance.

```
           services.AddAuthentication().AddOpenIdConnect(options =>
            { 
                options.Authority = "https://cognito-idp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/us-east-1_ydUErvZQJ/";
                options.ClientId = "2m50t6m94ec7pcnuk4179k15sf";
                options.ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.Token;

                options.Scope.Add("email");
                options.Scope.Add("profile");
                options.Scope.Add("openid");
                options.Scope.Add("aws.cognito.signin.user.admin");
            });
```

Unfortunately, I get an error that message.State is empty. I'm sure that I'm missing something in the config. I've consulted both the AWS Cognito and IdentityServer4 documentation and I can't seem to see what I'm missing.

```
           System.Exception: An error was encountered while handling the remote login.
 ---> System.Exception: OpenIdConnectAuthenticationHandler: message.State is null or empty.
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.RemoteAuthenticationHandler`1.HandleRequestAsync()
   at IdentityServer4.Hosting.FederatedSignOut.AuthenticationRequestHandlerWrapper.HandleRequestAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at IdentityServer4.Hosting.BaseUrlMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore.MigrationsEndPointMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore.DatabaseErrorPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore.DatabaseErrorPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```

Comment: Hi, Were you able to succeed in this ?